# Accessing all columns from MySQL table using flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get the columns for a MySQL table whether in a string or a list format.

Since I defined the table through my main app, I could use `dir(table_name)` to get a list of attributes but those contain private attributes and other built-in attributes like "query" or "query_class". Filtering these would be possible but I'm trying  to find an easier way to get the columns without going through the attribute route.

Between reading the flask-sqlalchemy documentation and sqlalchemy documentation, I noticed that using `table_name.c` will work for sqlalchelmy. Is there an equivalent for flask-sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask-SQLAlchemy does nothing to the SQLAlchemy side of things, it is just a wrapper to make it easier to use with Flask along with some convenience features.  You can [inspect orm objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/inspection.html) the same way you normally would.  For example, [inspecting a model returns its mapper](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper).

```
m = db.inspect(MyModel)
# all orm attributes
print(list(m.all_orm_descriptors.keys()))
# just the columns
print(list(m.columns.keys()))
# etc.
```